# Found JS error in require.js, but not able to rectify from where it is coming. Please help

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I found the error in require.js like

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(y,h){"use strict";
```

With the around the thousand line that i can't share it here. But i am not able to reconfigure from where it is coming. In the error script i found some more lines that help you to suggest the error

```
    {h.onselectstart=functio/**
   * @license
   * slighly modified parse-headers 2.0.2 <https://github.com/kesla/parse-headers/>
   * Copyright (c) 2014 David Björklund
   * Available under the MIT license
   * <https://github.com/kesla/parse-headers/blob/master/LICENCE>
   */,$t=Object.prototype.toString;

And

    attributes.IV.subst/**
   * @videojs/http-streaming
   * @version 1.13.2
   * @copyright 2020 Brightcove, Inc
   * @license Apache-2.0
   */
var ol=function(e,t,i)
```

I searched all of theme, vendor, app folder but didn't see it in code. These are 2 npm pacakges and not able to found in our magento 2.3.5 version website. Any one can help on finding the solution or any idea how to move ahead to get the solution? You may check the image also here
[image]